# WakeAllConditionVariable by multiple threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Suppose 1 thread (T1) is sleeping on Condition variable(C1). Now a thread (T2) which doesn't have the lock on Critical section associated with the Condition Variable(C1) sleep call. What is the behavior in case T2 call WakeAllConditionVariable?

Edit: Addition to question. What if the WakeAllConditionVariable call is not guarded by critical-section?

Comment: Not sure I understand this question. You want to know what happens when a thread that doesn't own the crit-sec of a cv-pair invokes a broadcast condition variable signal? All waiters acquire the critical section in due-time are awoken, and *better* check their predicate before continuing or returning back to sleep, depending on how the wait-loop is structured.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. The thread which doesn't own the crit-sec of CV invokes broadcast.

Comment: Then the result will be exactly as I described. There is nothing about cvars that says the signaler (be it by broadcast or single) has to own the latch when invoking the signal, and in fact depending on the construction of your logic, may well-be advised *not* to own said-latch when invoking the signal.